# Слайд-шоу с jQuery

Tags: jquery

Помогите создать слайд-шоу из 5-и картинок, с возможностью передвигать их вперед и назад.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В помощь Вам плагин `Cycle`. Картинки автоматически прокручиваются по одной. Пользователь может перейти на любую понравившуюся картинки сам.
Либо `lightBox`. Пользователь сам должен щелкать на кнопку далее (назад), чтобы картинки  менялись.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

А готовый не подойдет ? 
Например [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: Я скачал этот, но там есть, который двигает 3картинки сразу. Как можно сделать так, чтоб по одному поменял?